# ModuleNotFoundError when importing custom Python package from PyPI

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, setup.py

I have been working on creating a custom Python package, "sumpackagesonar," and I am encountering an issue when trying to import it after installing it via PyPI. I have followed the necessary steps to upload the package to PyPI, and the installation appears to be successful. However, when I try to import the package using `import sumpackagesonar`, I receive a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumpackagesonar'" error.

Here is the structure of my package:

```
sumpackagesonar/
    __init__.py
    sum.py
    setup.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty, and the `sum.py` file contains a simple function to print the sum of two numbers. My `setup.py` file includes the necessary setup code:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='sumpackagesonar',
    version='1.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

To distribute the package, I created the `dist` directory by running `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` and then uploaded the contents of the `dist` directory to PyPI using `twine upload dist\sumpackagesonar-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl dist\sumpackagesonar-1.0.0.tar.gz`.

After successfully installing the package using `pip install sumpackagesonar`, it is listed in `pip list`. However, I encounter the mentioned `ModuleNotFoundError` when trying to import the package.

I have attempted various solutions, including modifying the package structure, checking the package name consistency, and reinstalling the package. However, the error persists.

Could someone please help me understand the possible causes of this error and provide potential solutions? I would greatly appreciate any guidance to resolve this issue and successfully import my custom package.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You should really use [Test PyPi](https://test.pypi.org/). Could you also include how are you trying to import the installed package?

Comment: I try to import the package as
import sumpackagesonar

Comment: When I check **my** package that I've pushed to PyPi, I can see the following files; `__init__.py  __pycache__  main.py`. But in your package, there's only; `INSTALLER  METADATA  RECORD  REQUESTED  WHEEL  top_level.txt`. There's no `__init.py__` or `__sum__.py`. Hmm.

Comment: Please check the package structure which is included in my question. I have included both `__init__.py` and `sum.py` along with `setup.py` in my package. Yahh.. I do not include `__pycache__main.py` file. Is it could be the possible cause of this error?

Comment: Yes, you included them but they don't come with your installation. `__pycache__` is not necessary.  What does `find_packages()` returns?

Comment: Please enlighten me with this concept. How it can be included in the installation?

Comment: I've never used `setuptools`, so I'm not sure. Either it doesn't include your files with `find_packages()` or there's something else.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I got my solution now!! Thank you a lot

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so we all can learn from it. :^)

Comment: I was not creating the `setup.py` file at the top-level directory. It should be created at the top-level directory not inside `sumpackagesonar`, means it should the same level as `sumpackagesonar` in my case. You have told me 'it is there but not included in the installation' from that I got my hint. Thanks for the contribution

Comment: @Sonarjit Could you post that solution as an answer to your own question with more details instead of just posting it as a comment?

Answer (score -3):

Your package is named "sumpackagesonar" and it contains the "sum.py" module, you should import it using "from sumpackagesonar import sum"

```py
from sumpackagesonar import sum
```

Comment: I would recommand not using `sum`. `sum` is already the name of a built-in function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: I could modify that, but the real problem is that even after I install the `sumpackagesonar` it show the error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sumpackagesonar'

Comment: This isn't the issue, as simple `import sumpackagesonar` should also work. The problem is that the package wasn't built correctly.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Could you please elaborate and explain how they should have properly built their package?

Comment: @Berkyjay - See Sonarjit's comment on the main question, which I asked them to post as an answer.  They didn't have the `setup.py` file at the correct level of the package directories.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Ah I see.  I didn't see the collapsed additional comments at the top.  Thx!